# Sign in with google not working with supabase react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i am making a mobile app with react Native. i want to add the option to sign in with google using Supabase. i can currently sign in with email and password no issues however useing the google provider it give error:

> undefined is not a function at Screens\User_Login.js:null in
> handlewithGoogle at
> node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in
> asyncGeneratorStep at
> node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in _next
> at node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in
> Promise$argument_0 at
> node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in
>  at Screens\User_Login.js:null in User_login at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:null
> in _performTransitionSideEffects at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:null
> in _receiveSignal
>
> - ... 21 more stack frames from framework internals

I have enabled google as a provider this is my config file

```
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto' //npm install react-native-url-polyfill
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'//npm install --save @supabase/supabase-js

const supabaseUrl = 'This is right in my code '
const supabaseKey = 'This is also right '

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey, {
    oauthProviders: {
        google: {
            url: (id) => `${supabaseUrl}/auth/v1/callback?provider=google&id=${id}`,
        },
    },
});


MY function to sign in:
const handlewithGoogle = async () => {
        try {
            const { error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithProvider('google');
            if (!error) {
                navigation.navigate('User-home');
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

This is the input in my return
 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handlewithGoogle}><Text style={styles.buttonText}> Continue with google</Text></TouchableOpacity>
```